# How can I extend my LVM partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have installed Proxmox on a machine. I need to extend `/dev/mapper/pve-data` with the unused space of `/dev/sdb5`

How can I achieve this?

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfbd89a5c

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        4096  40962047  40957952 19.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       40962048  43057151   2095104 1023M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       43057152 468854783 425797632  203G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       43059200 468854783 425795584  203G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xafd793e2

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           4096  40962047  40957952 19.5G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       40962048  43057151   2095104 1023M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3       43057152 468854783 425797632  203G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       43059200 468854783 425795584  203G fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data: 199 GiB, 213708177408 bytes, 417398784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting information in the question would be the output from `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`.

But if I take a few cautious guesses I would guess your `VG` is named `pve`, and your `lv` is `data`. The current physical volume is `/dev/sda5`, and you use the complete partition as your logical volume `data`. I also assume that /dev/sdb5 doesn't contain any data, so we don't risk losing anything?

I would start by changing the partition type of `/dev/sdb5` from `Linux raid autodetect`  to `Linux LVM`.

You do this with fdisk.

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb
Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1-5): 5
Hex code (type L to list codes): 8e
Changed system type of partition 5 to 8e (Linux LVM)
Command (m for help): w
```

Then you use `pvcreate` to make a new physical volume:

```
# pvcreate /dev/sdb5
```

You should now have 2 physical volumes listed when you type `pvs`

```
# pvs
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/sda5  pve       lvm2 a--  xx.xxg xx.00m
/dev/sdb5            lvm2 a--  xx.xxg xx.00m
```

Next step is to add the new physical volume into your Volume Group, `pve`. You do this by extending the Volume Group, by `/dev/sdb5`, with `vgextend`.

```
# vgextend pve /dev/sdb5
```

If you list information about your Volume Groups with `vgs` now you should see you have free space of the amount of the size of `/dev/sdb5`

```
# vgs
VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
pve       1   1   0 wz--n- xx.xxg xx.00m
```

To extend the logical volume `data`, you use the command `lvextend`. If you wish to use all of the available free space you can do it like this:

```
lvextend -rl +100%FREE pve/data
```

Of if you only wish to extend it with some of the space available, you can do it like this:

```
lvextend -rL +50G pve/data
```

The -r option resizes the file system for you, so you don't have to do that manually after.

Comment: That looks like it'll work. Make a backup first!!!

Comment: Thanks that did the job! Except lvexpand should be lvextend